# Insert a file at the beginning of a file possibly using sed

Tags: insert, sed

I think we already have similar post using sed to add "text" at the beginning of a file
Say: `sed -i '1i text' inputfile`

But here my question is: my text has many lines, so I put them in a file (file1). And I hope to insert the content in file1 at the beginning of file2.

How can I do that using sed, or other approaches?
thx

edit:

Sorry I'm myself complicating this question!
This is an idiot question because we can simply do by "cat"! :)
I'm an idiot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing

```
cat file1 file2
```

(Well, this is not "inplace" editing, though, you probably need to use a temp file or a buffer.)

Notice that in some shells, you will also be able to do

```
command < file1 < file2
```

Comment: @wang Happens to the best of us!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ((getline tmp < "TEMPLATE" ) > 0) { print tmp } 
             close("TEMPLATE")}
     { print }' ORIGFILE > NEWFILE && mv NEWFILE ORIGFILE
```

Using `vim`:

```
vim -c "read TEMPLATE" -c "read FILE" -c "wq"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (as an exercise as `cat` is the **obvious** choice):

```
sed '1{h;r file1'$'\n'';d};2{H;g}' file2
```

Comment: `sed  '1{h;r foo.txt'$'\n'';d};2{H;g}' bar.txt` seems to only output `foo.txt`.

Am I missing something?